# Seaborn Pairplot Legend Not Showing Colors

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have been learning how to use seaborn and pairplot in python. Everything here seemed to work fine but for some reason the legend will not show the associated colors. I have not been able to find a solution so if anyone has any advice, please let me know.

x = sns.pairplot(stats2,hue='Term',palette='husl',height=15)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first remove the wrong legend, and then add the legend via `plt.legend()`:

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.pairplot(tips[['day', 'tip']], hue='day', palette='husl', height=6)
g._legend.remove()
plt.legend(title='Day')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To change the ylabel: `g.axes[0,0].set_ylabel('distribution', size=15)`

Comment: And thank you for your advice on changing the y axis label.

Comment: The `pairplot` is intended to create a complete grid of combinations, which may make the interface a bit awkward looking when there is only one  subplot.  On the other hand, I don't think there is an easy way to create this particular plot without `pairplot`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add legend explictly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sns.pairplot(stats2,hue='Term',palette='husl',height=15) 
x.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm still getting the legend without the colors, but thank you though.