# Seaborn pairplot legend don't show colors and labels

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm using seaborn 0.11.2 but I have troubles seeing the legend of the seaborn pairplot.
Here is the code: all is working fine except for the legend

```
for x in x1_categorical:
   plt.figure()
   sns.pairplot(data=x1[[x,'weight']],hue=x, palette='husl', height=4, aspect=4)
   plt.title(x)
```

I cannot see neither color or labels. I have already tried what suggested here: [Seaborn Pairplot Legend Not Showing Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374807/seaborn-pairplot-legend-not-showing-colors)

I have no clue, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anything happen if you write plt.legend()?

Comment: Use `plt.legend()` as seaborn is build using matplotlib and hence it will render fine.

Comment: Without test data it is hard to guess  what you want to do. Could you explain a bit? `pairplot` creates plots for combinations of numeric columns. And `hue` with a legend is meant for categorical columns (e.g. using `hue='species'` for the iris dataset).  Are `x` and `weight` numerical? The meaning of using `hue=x` is hard to understand. What exactly do you expect to see in the legend? Could you add an image of one of the plots? Also note that in your code `plt.figure()` creates an empty plot, as `pairplot` is a figure-level function that creates its own new figure.

Comment: @avats I have tried but this error occours to me 'No handles with labels found to put in legend.'

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the observation!x is a categorical variable (so object type) while weight is a numeric one. I can't add an image because unfortunately I haven't enough reputations but the graph is working fine so why the graph works and not the legend?

Comment: @JohanC basically what I want pairplot to do is to show a comparison between each occurrence with respect to the target, weight in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, `x1_categorical` contains categorical column names. Taking seaborn's penguin dataset as an example, the current code would look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x1 = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
x1_categorical = ['species', 'island', 'sex']
for x in x1_categorical:
    g = sns.pairplot(data=x1[[x, 'body_mass_g']], hue=x, palette='husl', height=4, aspect=3)
    plt.title(x)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

When I try this (seaborn 0.11.2), I get plots such as:

[image: sns.pairplot with 1 numerical and 1 categorical column]

These seem to be kdeplots for the numerical column, using the categorical column as hue. Unfortunately, the legends are empty, also when `plt.legend()` is tried.

An alternative is to explicitly create the kdeplots, for example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x1 = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
x1_categorical = ['species', 'island', 'sex']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=len(x1_categorical), figsize=(12, 4*len(x1_categorical)))
for ax, x in zip(axs, x1_categorical):
    sns.kdeplot(data=x1, x='body_mass_g', hue=x, palette='husl', fill=True, common_norm=False, ax=ax)
sns.despine()
```

[image: sns.kdeplots for different hue columns]

The example code creates one large figure, but if needed, separate plots could be created as well.

An alternative could use `common_norm=True, multiple='stack'`:

[image: sns.kdeplot multiple='stack']

Comment: It works fine this way! Thank you!